# SQL Query Results

Tags: sql, database

I have to write a custom interpreter that simulates SQL `select` queries on a database with three tables: `A`, `B`, and `C`. My question is as follows: do the following queries return the same results?

```
select A1
from A
where A1 = 1;

select A1
from A, C
where A1 = 1;
```

As I have it written, these two provide different results, because of the added table in the `from` clause. But I'm not sure if that's right; should the results depend on the tables in the `from` clause or the joins (or lack thereof) in the `where` clause?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Second will return all the rows matching de A where Clause and all the row from the C table. Since there is no relation defined between those table. It's often call a cartesian product.

If you want a relation between A and C you will need a join between those, such as A.C_ID = C.ID for a matching pattern, or LEFT | RIGHT join depending on the set of result you want.

Comment: It's also sometimes referred to as a `CROSS JOIN`.